# Kubernetes: High CPU usage

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cluster-computing, rancher

I am using Rancher. I have deployed a cluster with 1 master & 3 worker nodes.
All Machines are VPSes with 2 vCPU, 8GB RAM and 80GB SSD.

After the cluster was set up, the CPU reserved figure on Rancher dashboard was 15%.  After metrics were enabled, I could see CPU used figures too and now CPU reserved had become 44% and CPU used was 16%. I find those figures too high. Is it normal for Kubernetes a cluster to consume this much CPU by itself?

[image]

[image]

Drilling down into the metrics, if find that the networking solution that Rancher uses - Canal - consumes almost 10% of CPU resources. Is this normal?

[image]
[image]

Rancher    v2.3.0
User Interface  v2.3.15
Helm    v2.10.0-rancher12
Machine     v0.15.0-rancher12-1

[image]

Comment: Which version of rancher are you using?

Comment: @OhHiMark Rancher v2.3.0

Comment: And could you please also provide some `kube-apiserver` logs? Before and after you enable the metrics.

Comment: I could after recreating the setup (I delete the VMs end of day). But not sure how. Besides...the question is not so much about the metrics workload. Even without metrics, 15% usage feels a lot. Does vanilla Kubernetes setup consume this much CPU?

Answer (score 1):

This "issue" is known for some time now and it affects smaller clusters. Kuberenetes is very CPU hungry relative to small clusters and this is currently by design. I have found multiple threads reporting this for different kind of setups. [Here](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2601) is an example.

So the short answer is: yes, Kubernetes setup consumes these amounts of CPU when used with relative small clusters.

I hope it helps.